# How i Connect the data that's in my folder without writing the specific path like:"C:\\Users\\Dima\\Desktop\\NewData\\..."

Tags: r

I am writing a script that's Requires Data Which is in my computer folder.

But eventually this script will be used in another computer, by another person.

I can't tell him to change all the paths to the data in the script.

How i Connect the data that's in my folder without writing the specific path

Like:"C:\Users\Dima\Desktop\NewData\..."

Comment: You could require that the files be in a local directory. In other words, the script will refer to the data dir via a *relative* path like `./data` instead of an *absolute* path like `C:/users/etc...`

Comment: I tend to create small functions to create all paths to data, program or output folders at the start of the program so that it is easy to update. eg filePath <- function(...) paste("C:/Users/Dima",...,sep="/"). You can then use these to read in the data etc later in the program ie read.table(filePath("yourdat.txt"))

Comment: Use `setwd()` . That's what it's there for.  But back up a second - it'll be a lot easier for the other user to run a `function` than a `acript` .

Comment: You could also rely on environment variables: see `Sys.getenv("HOME")` as an example of an already existing one, or create your own (see `Sys.setenv`) and require that users do the same.

Comment: set the working directory and use relative paths. for instance `setwd("path/NewData")`. or set the wd via `Misc` menu. to get a file inside a subdirectory of `NewData` [your working directory (check with getwd())] called `folder`, you will use relative paths. for instance `dat <- read.csv("folder/file.csv")`. other ideas [here](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/using/workspaces) using RStudio

Comment: You can add a interactive window asking the folder. Take a look at `choose.dir()`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way of making your code shareable depends upon your use case.

As Carl Witthoft pointed out, most code should be encapsulated in functions.  These functions can then be packaged into packages and easily redistributed on other peoples's machines.  Writing packages is easier than you think.

For one off analyses, scripts are appropriate.  How you make them user-independent depends on who your users are.  If your are sharing the script with colleagues, try to keep your data on a network drive, then the link to the data will be the same for everyone.  If you are sharing your script with the world, then keep your data on the internet, and the link to the data will be a hyperlink, again, the same for everyone.

If you are sharing your script with a few people who don't have access to a common drive, and you can't put your data on the internet, then some directory manipulation is acceptable.

Change your working directory to the root of where your project files are.

```
setwd("c:/Users/Dima/My Project")
```

Then you can reference the location of the data using relative paths.

```
data_file <- "Data/My data file.csv"
my_data <- read.csv(data_file)
```

Assuming that you keep the directory structure within your project the same, then you only need to change the call to `setwd` on each machine.

Also note that the special location `"~"` refers to your user home directory.  Try

```
normalizePath("~")
```

That way, if you keep your project in that location, you can avoid reference to "Dima" entirely.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want that the user will enter to the code and change always the working directory path.